Condition for $s(t) + 2 \int_0^\infty s(\tau)s'(\tau+t) d\tau \geq 0$
Let $s$ be a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that

$s(t)>0$
$s(0) = 1$
$s'(t)<0 $

I am trying to find minimal conditions on $s$ for the inequality $s(t) + 2 \int_0^\infty s(\tau)s'(\tau+t) d\tau \geq 0$ to hold. I feel like $s(t)$ should be convex but it might not be sufficient.
Similarly, I also want to know whether these conditions are also sufficient for the inequality $s'(t) + 2 s'(0) \int_0^\infty s(\tau)s'(\tau+t) dt \geq 0$ to hols as well.
Any hint is very welcome, thanks!

Just a preliminary idea, having convexity $s(\tau) - s(t+\tau))\le t s'(t+\tau))$, then replace $s(\tau)$, then you need to prove a stronger inequality,
$$F(t) = s(t) + s^2(\infty) - s^2(t) - 2 t\int_t^{\infty} |s'(\mu)|^2 d\mu \ge 0$$
if seems you need an additional requirement on $\int_0^{\infty} |s'(\mu)|^2 d\mu$, Since $F(0) \ge 0$, if you can show $F'(t)\ge 0$, then it will suffice, that seems to enforce a bound like $-s'(0)\ge 2 \int_0^{\infty} |s'(\mu)|^2 d\mu$.
